# "php notice" on error log for commented lines in the script

Tags: php, apache, error-logging

My apache error log files are clogging with "PHP Notice" and "PHP Warning" messages which refer to lines that are commented on my script.

1. Is this a normal behaviour?
2. What's the rational here? (the lines are commented, why would I care if there's a division by zero there)
3. How do I get rid of these messages without deleting the commented lines from the script?

Just a quick example:

```
//$a = round($b["h"]/$c,2);
```

> PHP Warning:  Division by zero in *** on line 106, referer: ****

Comment: You could do this, but I would fix them `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);`  You won't get errors for commented lines, but often the line the error is reported on is not 100% accurate, It could be just before that line.

Comment: I would try to debug it but you can suppress php errors by placing @ at  the place of the error example @$a=...... and so on